# How to animate TextStyle in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

The text in one of my Composables is struck-through when a certain boolean variable is true. How can I animate this change in `TextStyle` on recomposition so that the line **fades in** rather than appearing and disappearing abruptly?

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    completed: Boolean
) {
    val textStyle = TextStyle(textDecoration = if (completed) TextDecoration.LineThrough else null)

    Text(
        text = title,
        color = textColor,
        style = textStyle,
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
    )
```

Comment: How do you want to animate?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thank you for pointing that out, I clarified it in my question!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it exists a way to animate a `TextStyle`.
Not a great solution, but just a workaround:

```
Box() {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !completed,
        enter = fadeIn(
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = duration)
        ),
        exit = fadeOut(
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = duration)
        )) {
        Text(
            text = title,
            style = TextStyle(textDecoration=null)
        )
    }
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = completed,
        enter = fadeIn(
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = duration)
        ),
        exit = fadeOut(
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = duration)
        )) {
        Text(
            text = title,
            style = TextStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough),
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gabriele's answer is also a decent workaround, but perhaps a simpler one would be to put the `Text` and the "`Stroke`", in a box, overlapping. Say,

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    completed: Boolean
) {

Box{
    Text(
        text = title,
        color = textColor,
        style = textStyle,
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
    )
  AnimatedVisibility (completed) {
   Box(Modifier.width(1.dp)){
     //Empty Box of unit width to serve as the stroke
    // Add background modifiers to match the font color
   }
  }
}
```